# Android emulator native player on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, native

I am working on something that tracks what I'm playing on native music player. Only problem is, that emulator doesn't seem to have any music on it. I'm using Eclipse for my project and I couldn't find answer anywhere. So, is there any way to get music in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, there is.

- Go to the **DDMS** pane, select the emulator.
- Select the `/mnt/sdcard`.
- Copy (there's an icon with a red arrow pointing to a phone) the file/s you want in it.

[image]

Comment: Got to that part, now its saying read only file system. I have 2 gib sd card assigned to it.

Comment: Close and restart the emulator, check out Wipe User Data.